# How to configure Maven to build two versions of an artifact, each one for a different target JRE

Tags: java, maven, target

I have a maven module that I need to use in the J2ME client and in the EJB server. In the client I need to compile it for target 1.1 and in the server for target 1.6 .

I also need to deploy the 1.6 version to a Nexus repository, so the members working on the server project can include this dependency without needing to download the source code.

I've read at http://java.dzone.com/articles/maven-profile-best-practices that using profiles is not the best way of doing this, but the author didn't say what's the best way.

Here is my pom.xml:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <parent>
        <artifactId>proj-parent</artifactId>
        <groupId>br.com.comp.proj</groupId>
        <version>0.0.4-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </parent>

    <artifactId>proj-cryptolib</artifactId>
    <name>proj - Cryto Lib</name>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>br.com.comp</groupId>
            <artifactId>comp-proj-mobile-messages</artifactId>
            <version>0.0.2-SNAPSHOT</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>

        <plugins>

            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.3.2</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.3</source>
                    <target>1.1</target>
                    <fork>true</fork>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

        </plugins>

    </build>

</project>
```

Comment: Why do you need target 1.6 for the server?

Comment: @PhilippeMarschall : I don't know. I'm working on the client, the other members that are working on the server said they really need it.

Comment: That doesn't really make sense. Code compiled with target 1.1 works fine in a Java 6 VM.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can configure this via the Maven compiler plugin.

Take a look at the [Maven compiler plugin documentation](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-compiler-plugin/examples/compile-using-different-jdk.html).

You could enable this via different profiles for instance.

If you only want to have different target versions you could simply use a variable target.  Something like this:

```
<plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.3.2</version>
    <configuration>
        <source>1.3</source>
        <target>${TARGET_VERSION}</target>
        <fork>true</fork>
    </configuration>
 </plugin>
```

Comment: If I understood, using this I will be able to use two different versions of javac. This is not what a want. I want this module being compiled with target 1.1 when it's used in the client project and with target 1.6 when used in the server project. We was trying to do this with profiles, but I've read that using profiles to build two different artifacts is not a good practice.

Comment: Yes that's correct, you would be using two different javac versions.  Updated my answer.  Not sure why using profiles would be a bad practice?

Comment: You might want to add that you'll need to use classifiers to specify alternate names to your packaged archive/deliverable, if you intend to build both at once.

Comment: I also don't know why, so I'm going with profiles. @haylem : classifiers?

Comment: @AlexOliveira: I added an answer with some details about that. Regarding profiles, they're often frown upon as they **cann** be an indicator of a badly designed build where you tend to fix things with profiles, and hurt your build's portability. I'd say that if you want and need it to work mostly for you, nobody cares. But if it's a project to be supported and built by a large range of people with different settings and environments, then you ought to be careful with that.

Answer (score 10):

As Haylem suggests thought you'll need to do it in two steps, one for the compile and one for the jars.

For the compiler

```
<plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.5</version>
    <executions>
      <execution>
        <configuration>
          <source>1.3</source>
          <target>1.5</target>
          <fork>true</fork>
          <outputDirectory>${project.build.outputDirectory}_jdk5</outputDirectory>
        </configuration>
      </execution>
      <execution>
        <configuration>
          <source>1.3</source>
          <target>1.6</target>
          <fork>true</fork>
          <outputDirectory>${project.build.outputDirectory}_jdk6</outputDirectory>
        </configuration>
      </execution>
    </executions>
 </plugin>
```

And then for the jar plugin

```
<plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.1</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <goals>
              <goal>jar</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
              <classesDirectory>${project.build.outputDirectory}_jdk5</classesDirectory>
              <classifier>jdk5</classifier>
            </configuration>
          </execution>
          <execution>
            <goals>
              <goal>jar</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
              <classesDirectory>${project.build.outputDirectory}_jdk6</classesDirectory>
              <classifier>jdk6</classifier>
            </configuration>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
```

you can then refer to the required jar by adding a `<classifier>` element to your dependency. e.g.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>br.com.comp.proj</groupId>
    <artifactId>proj-cryptolib</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.4-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <classifier>jdk5</classifier>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Great answer ! The only that correctly answers the question IMHO.

Comment: Does this configuration still work?

Answer (score 2):

*To complement my comment to wjans' answer, as you requested more details.*

The following would have the compiler plugin executed **twice** to produce two different sets of classfiles, identified by what is called a `classifier` (basically, a marker for Maven to know what you refer to when a single project can produce multiple artifacts).

Roughly, something like:

```
<plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.5</version>
    <executions>
      <execution>
        <configuration>
          <source>1.3</source>
          <target>1.5</target>
          <fork>true</fork>
          <classifier>jdk5</classifier>
        </configuration>
      </execution>
      <execution>
        <configuration>
          <source>1.3</source>
          <target>1.6</target>
          <fork>true</fork>
          <classifier>jdk6</classifier>
        </configuration>
      </execution>
    </executions>
 </plugin>
```

Note that people sometimes frown on using `classifier`s, as they on using `profiles`, as they can possibly mean that your project should be scinded in multiple projects or that you are harming your build's portability.