# Multi-JDK Maven builds using classifiers

Tags: java, maven

Maven docs explicitly suggest classifiers as a solution for multiple JDK support:

> The classifier allows to distinguish artifacts that were built from the same POM but differ in their content. It is some optional and arbitrary string that - if present - is appended to the artifact name just after the version number. As a motivation for this element, consider for example a project that offers an artifact targeting JRE 1.5 but at the same time also an artifact that still supports JRE 1.4. The first artifact could be equipped with the classifier jdk15 and the second one with jdk14 such that clients can choose which one to use.

I have never seen a working example of this. Is the documentation wrong, or is it somehow possible to actually make Maven build the same artifact multiple times with different JDKs (and obviously distinct source directories, since they will have different syntax (e.g. diamond or lambdas)) and, most importantly, deploy them together?

Seems like this kind of thing would be a basic requirement for potential support of JEP 238, too.

Answer (score 1):

The documentation is not wrong. It is just giving an example of how classifiers can be applied, in this case by targeting several JREs.

For how this can be done, there may be several ways to do this. See [How to configure Maven to build two versions of an artifact, each one for a different target JRE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10920142/how-to-configure-maven-to-build-two-versions-of-an-artifact-each-one-for-a-diff) for a related problem. You can also trigger different execution with Maven profiles. In this case, each profile triggers a different configuration of the `maven-jar-plugin` with a different classifier:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.6</version>
    <executions>
      <execution>
        <phase>package</phase>
        <goals>
          <goal>jar</goal>
        </goals>
        <configuration>
          <classifier>jdk14</classifier>  
        </configuration>
      </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

Comment: Using multiple profiles necessitates multiple lifecycle executions, doesn't it? How would you deploy them together, then?

Comment: I also use the toolchain plugin due to different JDK locations on different build systems, and I know of no way to define the toolchain for an individual plugin execution.

Comment: @Gordon AFAIK you would need to run multiple profiles to deploy the multiple artifacts. I have never used the toolchains plugin before...