# Multi-JDK SBT builds using classifiers

Tags: scala, sbt

I would like to publish a library with a custom classifier. How to update the artifact definitions in `sbt` to add this custom classifier? Moreover, how to publish a library with multiple classifiers? For instance, classifier for jdk8, jdk15, etc.

Comment: I would like to release a scala library compiled against different java versions and have a classifier to indicate the java version. There would be one JAR per java version, for example for jdk8, jdk11, jdk15.

Comment: You can see [here](https://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/jdk-compatibility/overview.html) the JDK COMPATIBILITY chart. Did something fail for you? What is the reason for this question?

Comment: I am trying to achieve in SBT what can be done in Maven. Examples: [Multi-JDK Maven builds using classifiers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30876508/multi-jdk-maven-builds-using-classifiers) and [How to configure Maven to build two versions of an artifact, each one for a different target JRE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10920142/how-to-configure-maven-to-build-two-versions-of-an-artifact-each-one-for-a-diff)

Comment: I changed the question to make it clearer.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification! Do you want to publish different package for each classifier, or publish one with multiple classifiers?

Comment: I would like to have one package per classifier. For example: library-1.0.0-jdk8.jar, library-1.0.0-jdk15.jar.

Comment: I didn't figure it out yet. But my answer shows how to add a single classifier. I'll update how can that be done.

Answer (score 0):

In order to add classifier to your artifact, you should add to your `build.sbt`:

```
artifactClassifier := Some("customClassifier")
```

It will publish jar with classifier `customClassifier`.

I am not yet sure how to do that with multiple classifiers.